# correction of sentences

Tags: phrase-request

Which is correct and why ?

1) Only when you have your children **will you** understand how difficult it is.

2) Only when you have your children **you will** understand how difficult it is.

Comment: What is the source of these questions? Do you just want to check the validity of these sentences, just to make sure it is correct?

Comment: my doubt is when to use "Will you" and when to use "you will"

Comment: In both sentences the word 'your' is not necessary and also inaccurate.  Either say 'your own' or  omit the word 'your'.

Answer (score 2):

> Only when you have [your own] children will you understand how difficult it is.

or

> When you have [your own] children you will understand how difficult it is.

Would all read correctly. In both sentences 'your own' is optional but more precise depending on the nature of 'it'. Does it mean actually your own children (biological) or could it mean fostered or adopted children? where 'Your own' would refer to the former specifically.